# Wordpress - создание файла шаблона для кастомного типа записи

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал свой тип записи:

```
function createServicesPostType () {
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Услуги',
    'singular_name' => 'Услуга',
    'add_new' => 'Добавить услугу',
    'add_new_item' => 'Добавление новой услуги',
    'edit_item' => 'Редактировать услугу',
    'new_item' => 'Новая услуга',
    'view_item' => 'Просмотр услуги',
    'not_found' => 'Услуга не найдена'
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' )
);

register_post_type('services', $args);
}

add_action( 'init', 'createServicesPostType' );
```

Для каждой отдельной записи этого типа я создал файл шаблона — `single-services.php`. Тут все работает нормально. При переходе на запись этого типа корректно отрабатывает `single-services.php`. Но мне нужно также создать отдельный файл шаблона для вывода списка всех этих записей. Как-будто бы все эти записи относились к одной таксономии и отрабатывал бы по сути шаблон вывода записей определенной таксономии (`taxonomy-имя_таксономии`). Но по структуре проекта таксономии для данного типа записей не нужны по сути, не хотелось бы добавлять лишнее в проект. Есть ли возможность создать такой шаблон для вывода списка записей конкретного типа не прибегая к созданию таксономии? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: archive-services.php

Comment: В таком случае отрабатывает index.php

Comment: @ДенисКорх  **noname228** правильно написал(а). archive-services.php  отработает раньше index.php https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png. После создания кастомного типа пересохрани пермалинки.

Comment: Файл archive-services.php создан, настройки ссылок также пересохранил, но почему-то все равно срабатывает index.php

Comment: А вы не изменяли стандартный wp_query?

Comment: Попробуй добавить `'has_archive'        => true,` в $args и пересохрани пермалинки

Comment: Спасибо, заработало (добавил 'has_archive' => true в $args)